# How does pruning people correct the timeline?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel, loki

I feel like pruning people from timelines is a major plot hole in the way time travel in the MCU is handled.

In the TV series Loki, you learn the Time Variance Authority (TVA) is controlling the timeline to make sure certain events happen the exact same way across all the timelines.

However, Kang clearly states that there are other versions of himself, across other timelines in the multiverse, that do not share his thoughts on this. This in itself seems contradiction - for Kang to control the timeline and avoid branches, wouldn't every Kang across every timeline in the multiverse, would have to be doing the exact same thing? Otherwise the timelines controlled by conflicting Kangs would have branched into each other a long time ago.

Furthermore, the TVA explain how crucial Loki is in making sure others reach their fullest potential. But, if Loki is pruned from his own timeline, would that not affect, and potentially change the outcome of the timeline in itself? It's not like they can slide in another Loki from another timeline, as *that* timeline would then be without a Loki.

Comment: This all seems very opinion-based. It works the way it works because that's how it works...

Comment: Opinion based in what regard? I'm asking a question based on the supplied facts.

Comment: Your idea of a "plot hole" seems to be based on what you didn't like and felt should have been written differently.

Comment: The discussion around this is all very interesting but is going on a bit especially for a closed question. If the question should be reopened you can do so and make answers to address these points else this isn't really the place to have it. The conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131491/discussion-on-question-by-brandon-how-does-the-tva-correct-the-timeline-by-pruni), please continue there if you wish.

Comment: @Brandon: sure — but as far as we can see, whatever changes the TVA makes to the timelines they visit, they don't lead to bad He Who Remains variants starting (restarting?) multiversal wars. As He Who Remains explains, that's the goal.

Comment: Other than the facts that I've already provided here's a few more- Sylvie bombs the sacred timeline to create a rapid branching and distract the TVA. If the bombs just reset the timeline, why would it branch?   Secondly, they ignore certain areas of the timeline when an extinction level event occurs, because the cause of the branch will be destroyed. Which is no different than my original theory, but it's pruned naturally instead of TVA interference. My only theory is that there is an allowable error in the timeline. But this is also contradicted by the whole premise of the "sacred timeline"

Comment: @Brandon - If this response is directed at me, you should copy and paste it into [the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131491/discussion-on-question-by-brandon-how-does-the-tva-correct-the-timeline-by-pruni) created by TheLethalCarrot, so we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, it looked like you had an interesting core question hidden in there, and I've taken the liberty to make a few (possibly large) edits to pull out the salient points. You're free to rollback those changes, and edit your own. As for the reaction you're getting over the initial question being opinion based, check out the [tour] and [ask]. The problem with asking about plot holes in general is that because fiction requires a certain amount of 'suspension of disbelief' it can be subjective whether a work is consistent or not in what it tells you based on personal views

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I wanted to say I appreciate the info. I will try to be better at conveying my question in the future. Sometimes my thoughts are coming at me so fast, I have a hard time organizing them in a coherent manner. Being told my question is opinion based when the topic is sci-fi, threw me for a loop. Basically any question asked about that specific subject matter, could be considered subjective. Yes, claiming there is a plot hole is definitely opinion and maybe I should have left that part out. However, I felt the actual question was legitimate.

Comment: I knew Major Plothole. I served with Major Plothole. _You_, sir, are no Major Plothole.